# Determine if quantized Decimal was truncated

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I'm trying to accomplish is writing a function that returns a `Decimal` representation of an input, if it can be converted to a Decimal and if it has any level of precision **up to but not exceeding** a particular digit.

Suppose I have the following:

```
def check(input):
    d = Decimal(input).quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
    raw = Decimal(input)
    return d if d.compare(raw) == 0 else "FAIL"

print(check(7.123))  # Returns 'FAIL'
print(check('7.123'))  # Returns 'FAIL'
print(check(7.12))  # Returns 'FAIL'
print(check('7.12'))  # Returns Decimal('7.12')
```

As you can see, if a string is passed in, it fails if there is any truncation of the value, and returns the `Decimal` representation if there is no truncation. On the other hand, floats always fail.

Is there a way to fix this check to see if a quantized `Decimal` value was truncated? Or is there simply some more direct way that I'm missing?

Comment: Do you mean for the third call (float) you want it to succeed?

Comment: Yes, or more broadly I want to be able to truncate the value to a particular level of precision and then know if that occurred or not.

Answer (score 2):

The issue occurs because when you convert a `float` instance into `Decimal` , it converts the internal representation of the float , Example -

```
>>> Decimal(7.12)
Decimal('7.12000000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875')
```

From [documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects)

> If value is a float, the binary floating point value is losslessly converted to its exact decimal equivalent. This conversion can often require 53 or more digits of precision. For example, `Decimal(float('1.1'))` converts to `Decimal('1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625')` .

Once way to fix this , would be to convert the `float` to `str` , before passing it into `Decimal` . Example -

```
>>> Decimal(str(7.12))
Decimal('7.12')
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> def check(input):
...     d = Decimal(str(input)).quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
...     raw = Decimal(str(input))
...     return d if d.compare(raw) == 0 else "FAIL"
...
>>> print(check(7.123))
FAIL
>>> print(check('7.123'))
FAIL
>>> print(check(7.12))
7.12
>>> print(check('7.12'))
7.12
```